# Blocking full IP range in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, ip, block, spam

I have a problem, get all this spam login attempts, have edited htaccess to try to block the IP group, but seems to go through anyway, anyone can tell me what to correct?

Ex, I want to block all from 141.101.xxx.xxx

Ex, attempt from 141.101.98.0 came through with the below in htaccess file.

Have tried removing .0 but that makes a 500 error....

Order Allow,Deny

Allow from all

Deny from 173.245.0

Deny from 162.158.0

Deny from 141.101.0

Deny from 108.162.0

thanks for all help :)

rgs
Stig

Comment: I think I found out after reading Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 162.158.158.0/16, only this gives error....
Deny from 141.101.0.0/16
Deny from 173.245.0.0/16
Deny from 108.162.0.0/16
Deny from 172.69.0.0/16

Comment: Nope.... didnt work at all, I have this now, one for each ip address, but still going through showing up in my history.....  Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 162.158.165.0
Deny from 162.158.167.0
Deny from 141.101.77.0
Deny from 141.101.99.0
Deny from 141.101.69.0
Deny from 173.245.52.0
Deny from 172.68.239.0
Deny from 172.69.134.0

Answer (score 0):

When I am stuck with .htacces I use [this](https://htaccessbook.com/block-ip-address/) handbook. I know it's not a solution but it might help others.